# Cannot have the same name in summary for two different collections in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a script like this:

```
loss = utils.get_loss(logits, volumes, FLAGS.stacks, 'train')
v_loss = utils.get_loss(v_logits, v_volumes, FLAGS.stacks, 'val')

summary_train_op = tf.summary.merge_all('train')
summary_val_op = tf.summary.merge_all('val')
```

in utils:

```
def get_loss(logits, y, stacks, mode):

    loss = []
    for stack in range (0, stacks):
        tmp = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(logits[stack] - y))
        loss.append(tmp)
        tf.summary.scalar('loss_stack_' + str(stack), tmp, collections=[mode])

    return loss
```

However, I get two different variables for example: loss_stack_0 with mode train I get loss_stack_0 and for loss_stack_0 with mode val I get loss_stack_0_1

Why is it appending numbers behind the actual name for different collections?

Comment: Could you specify what your `utils` module is? And if it's your own, then maybe how `get_loss` works?
For debugging, I strongly suggest two things:
1) Make sure that you finalize the graph right away when you are done defining it.
2) Use the tensorboard graph visualizer to make sure that your ops are all defined the way you expect. (This might not help too much in this case, though, but you never know)

Comment: Yeah the input of the utils.get_loss is basically what I wrote after: get_loss.
What exactlyy do you mean by "make sure that you finalise the graph" in 1) @DrK

Comment: I have in the past found that I accidentally wrote my code in a way that continuously added ops to the graphs when I did not expect it. If you run `graph.finalize()`, then it will raise an exception if your code tries to add more ops.
With respect to `get_loss`, can you paste the code of that function? Presumably that is where the summary ops are created and if there is a bug, it would be in there.

Comment: Okay I have posted the `get_loss`. When should I call `graph.finalize()` Just before I start my session? @DrK

Comment: I think my graph gets duplicated. When shall I call graph.finalize() @DrK

Comment: When you have finished defining the graph, you can call `graph.finalize()`. If the graph is somehow duplicated before this point, this won't help you. However, if you code by mistake tries to write to the graph while you are training, for instance, this will cause it to raise an exception.

Comment: Ah okay, Well I am using my inference function twice. Cause I use Batch-Normalization and therefore I have to have similar graphs and reuse the weights. @DrK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming of tensorflow ops has nothing to do with collections!

Collections are lists that you can use at your discretion to keep track of different ops. They have no effect on where the op is written in the graph or how it is named. For this, you'd want to use name scoping (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/name_scope).

For example, you could write your code snippet like this instead:

```
with tf.name_scope('train'): # this line should only run once!
    loss = utils.get_loss(logits, volumes, FLAGS.stacks, 'train')
    # Put everything else you want to define inside
    # the `train` name_scope here

with tf.name_scope('val'):
    v_loss = utils.get_loss(v_logits, v_volumes, FLAGS.stacks, 'val')

summary_train_op = tf.summary.merge_all('train')
summary_val_op = tf.summary.merge_all('val')
```

This should give you op names like `train/loss_stack_0` and `val/loss_stack_0`

Please note that if you do the following, you will end up with two different name scopes:

```
with tf.name_scope('my_scope'):
    # Tensorflow creates a new name scope 'my_scope'
    a = tf.constant(5, name='A')
    # This constant will have the name `my_scope/A`

with tf.name_scope('my_scope'):
    # Tensorflow creates a new name scope, but 'my_scope'
    # is already taken, so instead it creates 'my_scope_1'
    b = tf.constant(9)
    # This constant will have the name `my_scope_1/B`
```

Comment: What exactly is a tensor flow op? So what is the op in this case? You said the ops name is: `train/loss_stack_0`. But what is the op itself?

Comment: And why does it only work when name_scope is above utils.get_loss() rather than above the summary.scalar() op itself?

Comment: Yeah but this also gives me: train/loss_stack_0 and train_1/loss_stack_1. What I want is the other way around: I want loss_stack_0/train and loss_stack_0/val ? How would you do that?

Comment: My Problem is that I have two different inference functions for loss and v_loss therefore I have two different graphs and therefore I think it is just not possible to do what I want! Sorry for confusing you!

Comment: That is an excellent question! It almost deserves to be its own question on here if it's not already. When you use tensorflow, you are no longer programming in python. You are using python to write tensorflow code. Tensorflow is graph based, meaning that you describe your tensorflow "program" in terms of connected nodes in a graph. Each of these nodes denote an operation (or "op") that takes a tensor as input and either creates an output or a side effect.

Comment: If you run `tf.name_scope('train')` twice, tensorflow will assume that you are asking for new name scope each time and to avoid name space collisions, it adds a counter integer at the end of the name. If you want to reuse the same name scope, you can store object returned by the `tf.name_scope` function in a variable and use that instead of a string the second time you want to invoke the same name scope. I personally think it is easier to just get everything done within the same `with` block right away.

Comment: Okay, I cannot really follow. Can you extend your answer, to show me what you mean with '"within the same block right away"

Comment: Ok, now I do understand. Could I use reuse=true for the second term or its that just for variable scope ?

Comment: That's only for variable scopes.